# Switch from chrome extension is not applied until reload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension that shows a small preview of the website when hovering over a link.
I made a switch button on my extension and using chrome local storage I'm able to keep the state of that switch. However, when I turn the switch on in the popup, I need to reload the webpage for the preview to work. In other words, the change that I made in the extension is not being updated live on the webpage that I'm on. Which makes sense because the injected javascript file shouldn't change according to what the popup is doing.
How can I make it so that when the chrome extension switch is clicked, the webpage does something?

Answer (score 0):

I think your script is reading the local storage value (turned on/off status) on load (just once). You can modify it to check the local storage value when hover event is triggered.

Comment: the problem is the webpage can't access the local storage value and only the popup can with the error that says local undefined.